# Vue-material site is not responsive on phone

Tags: responsive-design, vue.js, material-design, vuejs2, vue-material

I'm using [Vue-material](https://vuematerial.github.io/#/) on my VueJS 2 site and it looks as expected on my laptop. It responds accordingly as I shrink the screen. However, when I emulate a smartphone or open the site on my smartphone it simply looks like a "shrunken" version of the computer layout.

I may be missing something basic here, but I'm not sure what it is.

Site in shrunken down browser window :
[image]

Site on smartphone :
[image]

Comment: Your site's HTML appears to be missing the meta viewport tag entirely.

Comment: @ceejayoz Doh! I knew it was something simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
```

add these two lines in your site's Html because it is missing meta viewport tag.
I hope it would help you.

Comment: Please could you be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

add this meta to your **index.html**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

Example index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>win-vue</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```